# configure log on appengine with spring and maven

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm building an application On GAE but I'm not able to configure log to show messages in the admin Console.

Can you give me an example please that shows how to work with log on gae?

I'm unable to import java.util.logging Package, so I'd like To use log4j.

Thank you.

Comment: did you read [this blog post](http://blog.xam.de/2010/03/logging-in-google-appengine-for-java.html)? I don't think you can completely avoid jul as that is what app engine uses underneath

Comment: Error was java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager. Please can you give me a complete example with maven pom.xml imports declaration with log for GAE?thank you